# Using XSLT for setting up a jssor gallery through a bunch of img tags

Tags: xslt

I have this XML document:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<content>
    <text>
        <img src='path/01.jpg'/>
        <img src='path/02.jpg'/>
        <img src='path/03.jpg'/>
    </text>
</content>
```

I would like to transform it in the HTML struct that the jssor gallery requires. This is what I want:

```
<div class='gallery'>
    <div data-u='loading' class='loading'>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div data-u='slides' class='slides'>
        <!-- each img tag will be transformed in to this. The rest of the html is just a fixed structure -->
        <div>
            <img data-u='image' src='path/01.jpg' />
            <img data-u='thumb' src='path/01.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u='image' src='path/02.jpg' />
            <img data-u='thumb' src='path/02.jpg' />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img data-u='image' src='path/03.jpg' />
            <img data-u='thumb' src='path/03.jpg' />
        </div>
    </div>

    <span data-u='arrowleft' class='arrowleft'></span>
    <span data-u='arrowright' class='arrowright'></span>

    <div data-u='thumbnavigator' class='thumbnavigator'>
        <div data-u='slides' class='slides'>
            <div data-u='prototype' class='p'>
                <div class='w'>
                    <div data-u='thumbnailtemplate' class='t'></div>
                </div>
                <div class='c'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is what I'm doing in XSLT:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:tpl='http://www.weblight.com.br/2015/XSL/Template'>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="content">
        <div class='jssor_component galeria'>
            <div data-u='loading' class='loading'>
                <div><xsl:comment> </xsl:comment></div>
                <div><xsl:comment> </xsl:comment></div>
            </div>

            <div data-u='slides' class='slides'>
                <xsl:for-each select='text/img'>
                    <div>
                        <img data-u='image' src='{@src}'/>
                        <img data-u='thumb' src='{@src}'/>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </div>

            <span data-u='arrowleft' class='arrowleft'><xsl:comment> </xsl:comment></span>
            <span data-u='arrowright' class='arrowright'><xsl:comment> </xsl:comment></span>

            <div data-u='thumbnavigator' class='thumbnavigator'>
                <div data-u='slides' class='slides'>
                    <div data-u='prototype' class='p'>
                        <div class='w'>
                            <div data-u='thumbnailtemplate' class='t'></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class='c'><xsl:comment> </xsl:comment></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

But this is what I'm getting

```
<div class="jssor_component galeria">
    <div data-u="loading" class="loading">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>

    <div data-u="slides" class="slides"></div>

    <span data-u="arrowleft" class="arrowleft"></span>
    <span data-u="arrowright" class="arrowright"></span>

    <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="thumbnavigator">
        <div data-u="slides" class="slides">
            <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
                <div class="w">
                    <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t" />
                </div>
                <div class="c"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Seems to me like for-each not works like in thought, because the slide div is empty :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding

```
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
```

as a child of the `xsl:transform` element in your XSLT so that the output XML will be readable, I do get the following output XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<div xmlns:tpl="http://www.weblight.com.br/2015/XSL/Template"
     class="jssor_component galeria">
   <div data-u="loading" class="loading">
      <div><!----></div>
      <div><!----></div>
   </div>
   <div data-u="slides" class="slides">
      <div>
         <img data-u="image" src="path/01.jpg"/>
         <img data-u="thumb" src="path/01.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div>
         <img data-u="image" src="path/02.jpg"/>
         <img data-u="thumb" src="path/02.jpg"/>
      </div>
      <div>
         <img data-u="image" src="path/03.jpg"/>
         <img data-u="thumb" src="path/03.jpg"/>
      </div>
   </div>
   <span data-u="arrowleft" class="arrowleft"><!----></span>
   <span data-u="arrowright" class="arrowright"><!----></span>
   <div data-u="thumbnavigator" class="thumbnavigator">
      <div data-u="slides" class="slides">
         <div data-u="prototype" class="p">
            <div class="w">
               <div data-u="thumbnailtemplate" class="t"/>
            </div>
            <div class="c"><!----></div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Which looks a lot like what you expected.

I see no way (analytically or empirically) that you could get XML output containing an empty `data-u="slides"` `div` as you indicated:

```
      <div data-u="slides" class="slides"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I was not aware that there was a little problem with my XML, all the img tags were inside a P tag, and so, the XML was not like I thought it was. To achieve the correct result I had to replace the for-each xpath expression 'text/img' for 'text//img'

Answer (score 1):

Surely

```
<xsl:for-each select='text/img'>
```

should be

```
<xsl:for-each select='div/img'>
```

Comment: Why? The input XML has no `div` element and the `img` elements **are** children of `text`.

Comment: It seems to me you'll get upvoted if you post the alphabet, in wrong order :-)